# Launch composable recomposition from non-composable context

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

> @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a
> @Composable function

I need to recompose my @Composable method from outside. Currently I found only the ad-hock way to change the state flag for it.

```
@Composable
fun Main(){
    var updateState by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Proceed(updateState, { updateState = it })

    Button(onClick = { updateState = true })
}

@Composable
fun Proceed(update: Boolean, onUpdate: (Boolean) -> Unit){
    val needUpdate by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(update) }
    //Here I ask some permissions or use other non-UI stuff with remember methods
    onUpdate(false)
}
```

But how to do it more optimal?

Comment: It's also possible to use viewModel but this is same bad practice.

Comment: What do you mean "bad practice"? Updating the state is not the same as invoking a Composable function, that is done behind the scenes by the Jetpack Compose framework.

Comment: It's not recommended to store local UI variables in `viewModel`, use `remember` instead.

Comment: Everything we hold in ViewModel are ui states and variables via MutableState/satate in JetpackCompose. You can see it in google sample repositories. https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/2410841f0cd2384789be0ad48528cabfbf097db2/Reply/app/src/main/java/com/example/reply/ui/ReplyHomeViewModel.kt#L87. And if you use stateful Composables like Proceed you won't be able to update it outside of that function because you remember it once and it can never react to change in `update `. Actually having non-stateful Composables and state hoisting is adviced not the other way around

Comment: Why you are calling an event `onUpdate(false)` inside of `Composable` function's body. Composables may be called multiple times and you can not controll how many times or in what order or when it is called.

Comment: Could you write a proper sample?